# Используя стандартные строковые функции переверните каждое предложение в тексте C++

Tags: c++, строки, функции, подстрока

### Есть некоторый текст. Используя стандартные строковые функции языка С++

- Посчитайте количество вхождений слово, заданного пользователем
- Посчитайте количество предложений в тексте
- Количество точек и запятых
- Переверните весь текст целиком
- **Переверните каждое предложение в тексте**

Помогите с последней функцией.
Вот начал что то писать:

```
int CountWords(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int count = 0;
    char *pos = strchr(str1, str2[0]);
    do
    {
        if (!strncmp(&pos[0], str2, strlen(str2)))
            count++;
        pos = strchr(&str1[strlen(str1) - strlen(pos) + 1], str2[0]);
    } while (pos);
    return count;
}
int CountSentenses(char *str)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '!' || str[i] == '?')
            count++;
    return count;
}
int PointsCommas(char *str)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == ',')
            count++;
    return count;
}
char ReverseStr(char *str)
{
    char tmp[10000];
    strcpy_s(tmp, str);
    for(int i = 0, j = strlen(tmp) - 1; i <= j + i; i++, j--)
        str[i] = tmp[j];
    return *str;
}
void ReverseSentences(char *str)
{
    char *buf = strtok_s(str, ".!?");
    while (buf)
    {
        for (int i = strlen(str); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            cout << str[i];
        }
        buf = (NULL, ".!?");
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас есть наработки кода? Если так то добавьте код в вопрос. Учебные материалы поддерживаются только в том случае, если вы пытались что-либо сделать.

Comment: void ReverseSentences(char *str)
{
 char *buf = strtok_s(str, ".!?");
 while (buf)
 {
  for (int i = strlen(str); i >= 0; i--)
  {
   cout << str[i];
  }
  buf = (NULL, ".!?");
 }
}

Comment: В вопрос добавьте

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: `языка C/c++` что это за язык?

Comment: язык с++, я скопировал задание. Предмет - Основы программирования на С/С++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, тогда уж что-то вроде

```
void ReverseSentences(char *str)
{
    for(char * s = strtok(str, ".!?"); s;
        s = strtok(NULL, ".!?"))
    {
        for(char * e = s + strlen(s) - 1, *b = s; b < e; ++b, --e)
        {
            char t = *b; *b = *e; *e = t;
        }
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

(см. https://ideone.com/5t9GkD)

Comment: Спасибо большое;)